# Recoding in ffmpeg by size

Tags: ffmpeg, size

Is there any way to recode in ffmpeg by setting the desired output size? I mean something like this

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -size 650MB out.mp4
```

So ffmpeg (or a wrapper) calculates the size of the picture, codec, bitrate, and so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `file size = bitrate * duration` and `bitrate = file size / duration`. You know your desired file size (650 MB) and your duration (see the output of `ffmpeg -i in.mp4`). Now read the [two-pass ABR example](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#twopass) in the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide). The example really requires the associated explanation otherwise I'd include it here.